# Setting Environmental Variables In LINUX

Tags: set, setenv

I use the following command to set an environmental variable for a library path.

```
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:$HOME/openmpi/lib
```

When I run the application that uses this path, I get the following error:

> Can not read: "/usr/X11R6/lib:/u/xeonp22/people/syedm/work/openmpi/lib:/u/xeonp22/people/syedm/work/openmpi//lib"

I noticed that there is a double forward slash in the last line.

```
"~/work/openmpi//lib"
```

where as the actual library path as I set it was

```
"~/work/openmpi/lib"
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: The double slash should not be a problem. I rather think that the fbeginning of the second part, with `/u/xeonp22` is  suspicious.

Comment: I do have the read permission for the "lib" directory

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid there is too much guesswork involved here from my side. With the given information I don't know what could be the reason, but a double slash should not be the problem. I'd look elsewhere, checking every directory mentioned in the error message concerning its correctness and accessibility.